# call db2 load statement from an odbc connection

Tags: import, load, db2, odbc, wizard

I have this txt file, formatted with the '|' character between columns, and this script generated by the db2 LOAD wizard:

```
  LOAD FROM "<path_and_name_of_the_txt_file>" OF DEL MODIFIED BY ANYORDER COLDEL|
  METHOD P (1, 2, 3) MESSAGES "<path_and_name_of_a_new_log_file>"
  REPLACE INTO DB2ADMIN.WEB_NOHAB_CONSOLI (RUC, RAZSOC, FECHA)
  NONRECOVERABLE INDEXING MODE AUTOSELECT LOCK WITH FORCE;
```

The script just works ok. Now I have to call it from my VFP form (cStatement contains all the LOAD from above):

```
SQLEXEC(nMyConn,cStatement)
```

but it fails with error SQL0104N
I've tried with "" and '' for the path parameters but the problem persists.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB2 CLP can run `LOAD` and other non-SQL commands that client applications cannot send over a driver-based connection. DB2 provides a system stored procedure called [`ADMIN_CMD`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023577.html), which client connections (ODBC, JDBC, etc.) can call to initiate any of several popular administrative commands, including `LOAD`.